# How can i override this pseudo-border Html Css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I´m creating a webapp on ReactJS. I downloaded and NPM which creates automatically a slide nav but when i open that navbar it shows me some kind of border.

[image]

I have tried everything. Add borders manually, add background color when focus element, change focus-withing, but i dont what it is.

```css
/* menu burger */
    .bm-burger-button {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      width: 3.5%;
      height: 30px;
      left: 2%;
      top: 2%;
    }

    /* Color/shape of burger icon bars */
    .bm-burger-bars {
      background: #373a47;
    }
    
    /* Color/shape of burger icon bars on hover*/
    .bm-burger-bars-hover {
      background: #109DFA;
      transition: ease-in-out .2s;
    }
    
    /* Position and sizing of clickable cross button */
    /* .bm-cross-button {
      height: 24px;
      width: 24px;
    } */
    
    /* Color/shape of close button cross */
    .bm-cross {
      background: #bdc3c7;
    }
    
    /*
    Sidebar wrapper styles
    Note: Beware of modifying this element as it can break the animations - you should not need to touch it in most cases
    */
    .bm-menu-wrap {
      position: fixed;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    /* General sidebar styles */
    .bm-menu {
      background: #222222;
      padding: 2.5em 1.5em 0;
      font-size: 1.15em;
      overflow: hidden !important;
    }
    
    .bm-menu:focus {
    display: none;
    }
    
    /* Morph shape necessary with bubble or elastic */
    /* .bm-morph-shape {
      fill: #373a47;
    } */
    
    /* Wrapper for item list */
    .bm-item-list {
      color: #b8b7ad;
      padding: 0.8em;
    }
    
    /* Individual item */
    .bm-item {
      display: inline-block;
      border: #222222;
      border-left: 3px solid yellow; 
    }
    
    /* Styling of overlay */
    .bm-overlay {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    
      .nav-user {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        background-color: #222222;
      }
    
      .ul-user {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
        list-style: none;
        width: 20%;
        margin-block-end: 0em;
        margin-block-start: 0em;
      }
    
      .ul-burger {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
    
      li {
        display: flex;
        margin-right: 5%;
      }
    
      .li-burger {
        margin-bottom: 10%;
      }
    
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
      }
```

this is my CSS

Comment: what exactly did you download, and how did you implement it?

Comment: I just downloaded react-burger-menu npm. Here it is https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-burger-menu and i implemented it as it seems there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `!important` to overwrite css codes ?

Something like this

```
.bm-burger-bars-hover {
  background: black !important; 
}
```